# Not able to synchronize users from Auth0 to Hasura

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql, auth0, hasura

I want to sync users from Auth0 to Hasura using [Flutter Auth0](https://github.com/devdennysegura/flutter-auth0) and Hasura Auth0 JWT Integration.

I am not able to sync any information in Hasura table from Flutter frontend, I am passing the `x-hasura-admin-secret` header.

Here is my code:

```
final HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(
            uri: 'https://apppp.herokuapp.com/v1/graphql',
            headers: {"x-hasura-admin-secret": "xxxxx"});
```

Can anyone please guide?

Comment: Rephrase title and content. Better formatting.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as automatic syncing. Check the documentation [here](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/auth/index.html) regarding authentication & authorization.